# Ruby - how to extract £ symbol in a string to float conversion

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm using Ruby On Rails to build an events app. I'm trying desperately to find a way to handle multiple bookings for a user - so they can choose to book multiple spaces (at the moment they can only book one at a time) and the app will convert that number into the correct price ( 10 tickets for £10 each will cost £100 etc).
With the help of SO & Google, I've looked at a number of methods to use in my bookings.rb model, this is the latest -

```
def total_amount
    quantity.to_i * strip_currency(event.price)
end

private

    def strip_currency(amount = '')
        amount.to_s.gsub(/[^\d\.]/, '').to_f
    end
```

I've also tried this -

```
    def total_amount
       self.quantity.to_i * self.event.price.to_f
    end
```

Both methods return 0(zero) when I click through to the payments page. It basically boils down to the £ symbol (or am I missing something else?). It's been suggested that this equation may work -

```
string[0..-1].to_f
```

However, I'm pretty new to this and not sure how or where I would integrate this into my MVC code in order for it to work. I'm not using the monetize gem, I'm using money-rails but there must be a simple way / line(s) of code that will allow this method to work.

Here's my booking_controller -

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
    @booking.user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

    Booking.transaction do
      @event.reload
      if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
        flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
      end
    end

    if @booking.save
      # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
      # #{} == puts a variable into a string
      Stripe::Charge.create(
        amount: @event.price_pennies,
        currency: "gbp",
        card: @booking.stripe_token,
        description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")
      flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
      render "new"
    end

    if @event.is_free?

      @booking.save!
      flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
      redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end
  end

  private

  def booking_params
      params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
  end
end
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree with Ruby - should I be using javascript for this?

Comment: I am not sure where do you retrieve the price. If you have to store it as a string I would change `Event#price` to return a float number. Or better, I would directly strip the currency before storing the price and store the price as a float.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do with the first method I posted above. I'm obviously doing it wrong as it's not working - how would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have already worked as expected

debug and check what values you are getting for `quantity` and `event.price`

```
amount = '£10'
quantity = 2

strip_currency(amount) 
#=> 10.0

quantity.to_i * strip_currency(amount)
#=> 20.0
```

Maybe you are not getting proper values in either amount or quantity

Comment: What do you mean? How do I check this?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead To test this I opened an interactive console for ruby. I put your code and input the step provided by Deepak. It indeed works.

Comment: apply debugger or binding.pry in that method maybe you are not getting the values you are expecting

Comment: Do I need to add something to my controller for this to work? I've added it to the question.